# How can I get an answer to a user when I don't have enough rep to answer his question directly?

Tags: support

An Ask Different user has a problem that I also had. I found a solution this morning and wanted to answer his question, but the question requires a 10 rep to answer. I have a six rep, so I can neither answer or comment on the question. I also looked for a way to message him, but found none. Is there a way to message him? Any ideas on how I can get this guy the solution to his problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post a link to the question. We can consider un-protecting it.

Or better: earn the reputation to answer it. You're only four rep points away. That's easy enough to obtain answering one, unprotected question with a great answer. Or doing some suggested edits to some questions and answers. Or some voting.

See [What is reputation? How do I earn it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for some suggestions on how to break the 10 rep barrier.

It's not arduous or time consuming.